# Multicolored labels or other text areas in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I write my app using JavaFX for GUI. I need put listview in interface while app will get colored messages (from other API, I already has converter). What I need put in listview, what can support multicolored text? I need many then one color in one list entry.

[image: See]

I already try use TextFlow, but nothing changed... Text is white.

```
// In converter (list of Messages to TextFlow)
public static TextFlow getTextFlow(List<Message> list) {
        TextFlow flow = new TextFlow();
        for(Message msg : list) {
            Text text = new Text(msg.getFullText());
            MessageStyle style = msg.getStyle();

            ChatColor color = style.getColor();
            String textstyle = "";
            if(!(color.equals(ChatColor.NONE) || color.equals(ChatColor.NONE)))
                textstyle += "-fx-text-fill: #" + TextColor.valueOf(color.name()).getHex() + ";";

            System.out.println(textstyle);
            for(ChatFormat f : style.getFormats()) {
                System.out.println(f.toString());
                switch (f) {
                case BOLD:
                    if(!textstyle.equals("-fx-font-weight: bold;")) textstyle += " ";
                    textstyle += "";
                    break;
                case ITALIC:
                    if(!textstyle.equals("-fx-font-style: italic;")) textstyle += " ";
                    textstyle += "";
                    break;
                case STRIKETHROUGH:
                    text.setStrikethrough(true);
                    break;
                case UNDERLINED:
                    text.setUnderline(true);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }

            text.setStyle(textstyle);
            flow.getChildren().add(text);
        }

        System.out.println(flow.getChildren());
        return flow;
    }
```

```
// In message add method
public void handle() {
        if(packet.getType().equals(MessageType.NOTIFICATION)) return;

        Message msg = packet.getMessage();
        System.out.println(msg.toString());

        TextFlow flow = MessageUtils.getTextFlow(msg.getExtra());
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            MainController.getInstance().getLogsListView().getItems().add(flow);
        });

    }
```

Comment: I don't see a `ListView` `setCellFactory`.

Comment: @Sedrick, no, I know about cells, but I need multicolored text in this cells...

Comment: The steps you need to achieve your goal are the same as in the link. You need to use `setCellFactory` with some conditions to determine what text gets what color.

Comment: Using `TextFlow` with multiple `Text` nodes is the correct approach for multicolored text. If that's not working for you then please _create_ a [mre] demonstrating the problem and add it to your question via an [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try replace Text to Label in TextFlow and it works!
Thanks for answers.
See converter's code below. Other code above I don't edit.

```
        TextFlow flow = new TextFlow();
        for(Message msg : list) {
            Label text = new Label(msg.getFullText());
            MessageStyle style = msg.getStyle();

            ChatColor color = style.getColor();
            String textstyle = "";
            if(!(color.equals(ChatColor.NONE) || color.equals(ChatColor.NONE)))
                textstyle += "-fx-text-fill: #" + TextColor.valueOf(color.name()).getHex() + ";";

            System.out.println(textstyle);
            for(ChatFormat f : style.getFormats()) {
                System.out.println(f.toString());
                switch (f) {
                case BOLD:
                    if(!textstyle.equals("")) textstyle += " ";
                    textstyle += "-fx-font-weight: bold;";
                    break;
                case ITALIC:
                    if(!textstyle.equals("")) textstyle += " ";
                    textstyle += "-fx-font-style: italic;";
                    break;
                case STRIKETHROUGH:
                    if(!textstyle.equals("")) textstyle += " ";
                    textstyle += "-fx-strikethrough: true;";
                    break;
                case UNDERLINED:
                    text.setUnderline(true);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }

            text.setStyle(textstyle);
            flow.getChildren().add(text);
        }

        return flow;
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I now see where the problem was. You're using `-fx-text-fill` but that's not a CSS property of `Text`. When using `Text` you have to use `-fx-fill` to change the text color via CSS. For more information, check out the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).